# How to proxy a web service, yielding utf-8-encoded xml, via a plone browser

Tags: python, ajax, character-encoding, plone, zope

I have a Plone 3.3 site which retrieves information from a RESTful web service; the service returns utf-8-encoded xml data. The requests are sent via a special browser (let's call it `@@proxy` for this question).  Everything is working fine as long as no non-ASCII data is returned.

The `get` method of the browser looks like this:

```
def get(self, thedict=None):
    """
    reduced version for stackoverflow
    """
    context = self.context
    request = context.request
    response = request.response
    if thedict is None:
        thedict = request.form
    theurl = '?'.join((basejoin(SERVICEBASE, thedict['path']),
                       urlencode(auth_data),
                       ))
    fo = urlopen(theurl)
    code = fo.code
    headers = fo.info().headers
    for line in headers:
        name, text = line.split(':', 1)
        response.setHeader(name, text.strip())    # trailing \r\n
    text = unicode(fo.read(), 'utf-8')
    # --- debugging only ... -- 8< ----- 8< ----- 8< ----- 8< ----- 8<
    CHARSHERE = set(list(text))
    funnychars = CHARSHERE.difference(XMLCHARS)
    if funnychars:
        funnychars = u''.join(tuple(funnychars))
        logger.info('funny chars: %r' % funnychars)
    elif 1:
        logger.info('funny chars: none')
    # --- ... debugging only -- >8 ----- >8 ----- >8 ----- >8 ----- >8
    response.setBody(text.encode('utf-8'))
```

First I didn't do anything about encoding (`unicode`, `encode`). However, this appears to be necessary; when non-ASCII data like umlauts etc. is contained (e.g. `INFO proxy@@w3l funny chars: u'\xdf'`), the browser doesn't like the result.  When I try the same request directly (to `theurl`, not via my `@@proxy` browser), it works.  The problem does not depend on the internet browser, i.e. both Firefox and IE cough.

There is a `Content-Type` header of value "`text/xml;charset=UTF-8`"; inserting a space character behind the semicolon didn't change anything.

**edit:** This is what Seamonkey says:

```
XML-Verarbeitungsfehler: Kein Element gefunden
Adresse: http://.../@@proxy/get
Zeile Nr. 1, Spalte 1:

^
```

(in English: xml processing error: no element found; row #1, column #1)

Since I'm not the author of the service, I'm not *entirely* sure the data is *really* `UTF-8` (although the HTTP header and the `<?xml ...>` line say so).

What is my mistake?  What can I do to find the problem? Am I missing something important about Zope's response objects and/or `urllib2.urlopen`?

I also tried something like that (condensed):

```
fo = urlopen(theurl)
raw = fo.read().strip()
try:
    text = unicode(raw, 'utf-8')
    logger.info('Text passes off as utf-8')
except Exception, e:
    logger.info('no valid utf-8:')
    logger.exception(e)
    text = unicode(raw, 'latin-1')
```

... or the other way round; I never got any decoding error.

I wrote the "raw" data to a file (`open(filename, 'wb')`) which I inspected with vim (`set enc? fenc?`), which yielded `utf-8`.

I'm on my wit's end.

Comment: Quick notes on your code: `elif 1:` can just be written as `else:`. You can just do `set(text)`, no need to use `list()` there. No need to cast the set to a `tuple()` when passing it to `join`; `u''.join(funnychars)` will work fine.

Comment: This should Just Work; setting the body to `text.encode('utf-8')` works just fine wherever I use it. You'll need to explain in more detail as to what goes wrong in the browser; what do you mean by *'the browser doesn't like the result'*?

Comment: Maybe doing your code more like this http://opensourcehacker.com/2011/08/02/ajax-proxy-view-with-python-urllib-and-plone/

Comment: @Martijn: Of course I know about `else:`, but `elif 1:` is easily switched on/off by changing one bit (`1` or `0`) ... I use this often for debugging / developing purposes.  For real logic, I use `else` ;-)

Comment: @Tobias: You wouldn't believe how many posters on SO do not know things like that...

Comment: As for the symptoms: Seamonkey says something like:
XML processing error: no element found"
Address: http://...
Row #1, column 1:
^
(my translation)
MSIE simply displays nothing.

Comment: Edited the question; added some more information about the error and things I tried ...